# Calling stored procedures in schema B from a stored procedure in schema A stopped working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Problem solving an application that stopped working all of a sudden. Exception complains about a stored procedure not being available.

My conclusion is that, for some reason, schema NGM2 no longer is able to use stored procedures in schema NGM209.

I was able to come up with a simple example to reproduce and illustrate the problem.

Create test functions in schemas NGM208 and NGM209:

```
SQL> connect ngm208@DB
SQL> create or replace function test return varchar2 as begin return 'TEST208'; end;
SQL> grant execute on test to NGM2;

SQL> connect ngm209@DB
SQL> create or replace function test return varchar2 as begin return 'TEST209'; end;
SQL> grant execute on test to NGM2;
```

Both functions are available in SQL, when connected to schema NGM2.

```
SQL> select ngm208.test from dual;
TEST208

SQL> select ngm209.test from dual;
TEST209
```

Now let's create stored procedures for these functions in schema NGM2.

```
SQL> create or replace function test208 return varchar2 as
  2     l_result varchar2(32767);
  3  begin
  4     select NGM208.test into l_result from dual;
  5     return l_result;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace function test209 return varchar2 as
  2     l_result varchar2(32767);
  3  begin
  4     select NGM209.test into l_result from dual;
  5     return l_result;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error
Errors for FUNCTION TEST209:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/18     PLS-00302: component 'TEST' must be declared
```

So here's the problem. NGM2 does not seem to be able to find stored procedures in schema ngm209, from within stored procedures. In SQL it's working as expected.

Is there a logical explanation for this, and if so what is it, or did something go really wrong in that database?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in 19.5. What is your 4 digits Oracle version ? Any security features enabled ? It looks like somehow privilege is not enabled in stored procedure *but* you have granted direct privileges (I mean without role): so this is not the explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have likely in schema `NGM2` an object named `NGM209`:

```
SQL> show user;
USER is "NGM2"
SQL> create sequence ngm209;

Sequence created.

SQL> @c
SQL> create or replace function test209 return varchar2 as
  2  l_result varchar2(32767);
  3  begin
  4   select NGM209.test into l_result from dual;
  5   return l_result;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION TEST209:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/16     PLS-00302: component 'TEST' must be declared
SQL> 
SQL> drop sequence ngm209;

Sequence dropped.

SQL> @c
SQL> set echo on
SQL> create or replace function test209 return varchar2 as
  2  l_result varchar2(32767);
  3  begin
  4   select NGM209.test into l_result from dual;
  5   return l_result;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL>
```

Comment: That was it!. Somebody added a table ngm209. 
Thought I was looking at a ghost with this problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Right; sometimes things start happening all of the sudden. Would it help if you try to *fool* Oracle by creating a **synonym** and address it in the function?

```
create synonym syn_test_ngm209 for ngm209.test;

create or replace function test209 return varchar2 as
   l_result varchar2(32767);
begin
   l_result := syn_test_ngm209;   --> no need to SELECT FROM DUAL!
   return l_result;
end;
/
```